# Ansible response file for bash script

Tags: bash, ansible, response

I have a Ansible playbook that downloads a `DB2.tar.gz` archive from Artifactory repo, unarchive and installs it on a remote server. 
The problem is that the installer uses a bash script, and asks me a bunch of stuff. I need to install it quietly `download-unarchive-install` it on the server, without the need of a user input or any sort of output (there will be one in a file).

Someone told me that i need to first install it manually so that the i get a response file with the answers and questions, which then i need to convert it into a response file for Ansible. And i have no idea how to do this. Can you guys give me a hand on that? The entire playbook is done, I just need to sort this thing out and I don't know if I need to use a `.yml` file or `.sh` , another `module` or anything in Ansible.

Thank you !

Comment: Most likely that "someone" meant to use [`expect` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html). This question is too broad for SO. The docs contain examples, no one can tell what is required in your case.

Comment: yeah, i m sorry.. i posted the thread and shortly after i found the expect module.. Sorry, and thank you

Comment: The expect module will work, but the response list is not in sequential order, but is just a key-value pair.  The key is the regex, and the value is the response you want to send.  Responses to identical questions must be in a sequential list.

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the script? Maybe try this -

```
exec < response.file
```

Just put the responses in order in the file on lines of their own.
Try this test as an example:

```
echo "yes
no
maybe">r
```

then create a tst script

```
exec <r

while read
do echo $REPLY
done
```

run ./tst, it should spit out the content of r.

```
# ./tst
yes
no
maybe
```

Comment: BTW, note that unarchive will handle the download for you. Cleaner to do in one step.